# Integrate .stop() into a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I am writing a CSS3 animate plugin, that animates elements with CSS3 Transitions and it not available with the jQuery native `.animate()`

Everything is working out great for now, but I would like to integrate the `.stop()` into the plugin. So the user is able to use my plugin the same way he would in native jQuery.

This is my code so far
http://jsfiddle.net/meo/r4Ppw/

Any idea how I could call the stop method of my plugin when jQuery `.stop()` is used? (And passing its arguments of course)

I have tried to read the jQuery source, to find out how it works, but its just to high standing for me, I need some explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me say this:

I am new to plugins and I'm not sure if this even solves your problem but I gave it a shot.

http://jsfiddle.net/r4Ppw/44/

Basically I updated your `stop()` definition to alert me that it was called and then added the following at the bottom of your plugin code.

```
var originalStop = jQuery.fn.stop; //store original method
jQuery.fn.stop = function(){ //redefine the jQuery method
  methods.stop(); //call your plugin code
  originalStop.apply(this, arguments); //call the original and pass the arguments along
};
```

The fiddle has a click function applied to the `div` that calls `stop()`.

Give it a try.

I hope it helps.

Comment: oh it works! Very nice thank you. Now its up to me to integrate this nicely into the function

Comment: you can see the result of your efforts here :P http://jsfiddle.net/meo/UWgE5/ thx again

Comment: @meo Awesome! Thanks for the example of the finished code. I learned a little bit as well.